# System.NotSupportedException: The entity or complex type 'Project.Models.MyModel' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, join, model

Is it possible to store the result of a join on two/more tables in a model?
for example
Say I have the models

```
public class model1{
  public string studentID {get; set;}
  public string Address [get; set;}
 }

public class model2{
  public int ID {get; set;}
  public string StudentName [get; set;}
}

public class model3{
   public string StudentName [get; set;} 
    public string Address [get; set;}
}
```

If model1 and model2 draw data from the databse, can i create model3 by joining the results from model1 and model2?

**EDIT**

So, i did something like

```
model3object = dbcontext.Model3.AsQueryable();
        model3object = from m1 in dbcontext.model1
                  let id = dbcontext.Model1.Select(x => m1.studentId).Cast<int>().FirstOrDefault()
                  join m2 in dbcontext.model2
                  on  id equals m2.Id
                  select new Result
                  {
                      studentName = m2.studentName,
                      Address = m1.Adress,
                  };
```

but i get the error

```
System.NotSupportedException: The entity or complex type 'ProjectName.Models.Model3' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.
```

How can I fix this please?

Comment: Models don't draw data from the database, basically Controller does it. You can run a join query in the controller and populate Model3's object with the resulting data and pass it to view for use.

Answer (score 0):

I would use two different models. The models used by storing values from the database and the viewmodel used for displaying data in in mvc.

Take a look at this small example:

```
var customerOrders = from o in myService.GetOrdersByCustomerId(id)
                     join p in myService.GetAllProducts() on o.ProductId equals p.Id
                     select new CustomerOrderViewModel
                     {
                         OrderId = o.Id,
                         ProductId = p.Id,
                         OrderDate = o.OrderDate,
                         ProductName = p.ProductName
                     };
```

You code do the same with your model1 and model2 and map these two models to one viewmodel.

Comment: Yes, I understand this, but i need to store this in a model to be accessed in my view. My view uses several model and this will just be one of them. That is why I cannot just return View(customerOrders) as it is.

Comment: Do you mean you want to return multiple types of models to the View?  I'm not following you here.  @MUG4N seems to have the same concept I was going to answer with. He's assuming you want to map (join) the two objects to one model and present that to the view. You can use any join statement you want, and create any 'joined' view model you want.

Comment: My view has a "supper" model class that contains 4 models. I want to join two of these in a joint query and pass it to my view along with the two other models.